# gsm call / sms send doesn't work from emulator/ddms perspective

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have problems simulating call or sms since telnet or ddms perspective on eclipse.
I'm connected to the device and some commands works (window scale,...)
If i try to simulate a gsm call then everything seems ok but i haven't anything on my emulator (nor incoming call nor notification)
then if i launch an "gsm list" command my inbound call is listed and i can cancel it

the same thing occurs with sms send everything seems ok (return OK) but there is no notification on the emulator nor sms in inbox :-(

i'm using the sdk r06 on a windows xp machine. I try with fresh avd on different platform :-(

Important : it has worked so i know it can work, but i would like to know why it doesn't work now ! Using ddms i don't see any trace on the log view.

thanks for your help

Comment: i see too that i have "No Service" on the emulator. And an "Error on searching for networks" if i go to the settings.
seems ok when i'm online :-(

Comment: Hi, I've got exactly the same problem - I'll post here if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know why it works but i found a thread which helped me to workaround this problem
==> use a bootchart 100 option when launching the emulator

source : http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg65710.html

hope it works for u too.

Comment: Excellent find - works a treat! Thanks very much, this was driving me insane.